# Relatively prime numbers proof.

Tags: prime-numbers

How do I rather quickly prove that $$a=2500137802, b=1420515313, c=3920653117$$ are relatively prime numbers? I know it has something to do with Euclidean algorithm, but still doesn't ring a bell to me.

Comment: Yes, this method I know, but it is not a rather quick proof and I would prefer someone showing me how to do this with reference to Euclidean algorithm. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The Euclidean principle is that $\gcd(a,\, b) =\gcd(a,\, b-a)=\gcd(a,\, b-\lfloor{b/a} \rfloor a)$: so you reduce $b$, then invert the couple and reduce $a$, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ Any common divisor divides $\,2\, =\, 3920653117 -2500137802 - 1420515313$

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but I don't really know how to make use of it.

Comment: @John Are you trying to show that all three have no common divisor, or that they are pairwise coprime?

Comment: I'm trying to show that all three don't have a common divisor.

Comment: @John Any common divisor divides the RHS above so it divides the LHS $= 2\,$ so .....

Comment: It's becoming more clear for me now. I'm just learning this stuff, therefore it's really hard to understand everything, even though it looks simple and i feel daft, but thanks. :D

Comment: @John Suppose $\,d\,$ is a common divisor of $\,a,b,c\,$ Then $d$ also divides all integral linear combinations of them, i.e. $\,d\mid ja+kb+nc\,$ for all integers $\,j,k,n.\,$ The Euclidean algorithm is one efficient way to search for the *least* positive such linear combination, which is easily seen to be their gcd. The above exercise was constructed  to help us quickly notice a very small linear combination $= 2.\ \ $